# How to move specific inner node out using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

How to transform XML using just XSLT 
from:

```
<cm:outer>
    <cm:inner>
        <cm:pk>14</cm:pk>
        <cm:extraInfos />
        <cm:uuid>0821acca-f86c-4201-b961-a0060ed970b0</cm:uuid>
        <name>TEST</name>
    </cm:inner>  
</cm:outer>
```

to:

```
<cm:inner>
   TEST
</cm:inner>
```

Comment: Is this an example of content that is part of a larger document? Otherwise, your example input is invalid and cannot be transformed. The "cm" namespace prefix is not bound to a namespace.

Comment: Do you have a **specific** question - or are you just looking for someone to do your work for you?